# VS2012 to VS2015 migration

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2015

Hi I am migrating my project from VS2012 to VS2015 and I ended up with the following error

**Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'mfc110.lib'**

I also search for mfc110.lib file in the installation directory of VS2012 and VS2015 but its not there.

I googled it found the following link but it did not help me

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/081c25ed-d068-4ef2-a08d-b5639d443c98/vs2012-linker-error-1104-mfc100lib

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602392/how-do-i-fix-the-linker-error-in-project-upgraded-from-vs2010-to-vs2013-where-th

Comment: @Pavdro I have gone through that link but this option is Under 

right click->properties->Configuration properties->C/C++->command line

but it is not editbale..its greyed out..
I am not able to edit it.

Comment: Do you happen to have an Express Edition of Visual Studio 2012? The Express Editions do not contain MFC.

Comment: @llnspectable No I am having VS2015 professional addition..

Answer (score 0):

[error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc90.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330058/error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-mfc90-lib)

Try to link the project to the new .lib (probably something like mfc120.lib)
Seems to be the same problem just with an older version of VS. As well in your posted URL it states to relink the project to the new .lib

Comment: I am not able to understand how to relink the project with new ,lib files.

Comment: Changes the project so that it uses the Visual Studio 2015 compiler and libraries (PlatformToolset = VisualStudio v140).

For C++/CLI projects, changes the TargetFrameworkVersion to the .NET Framework 4.5.2.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh690665.aspx

it seems you are using some old librarys and need to update them to the newer ones

Answer (score 0):

One of your objects files or other libraries (maybe third party) you use still links to the old VS version.

Try the /verbose option of the linker, to see what module wants to link to the old libraries.